# Ошибка XFC0000 Cannot resolve type "clr-namespace:SmartYard.Pages: NewsPage"

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема:

```
XFC0000 Cannot resolve type "clr-namespace:SmartYard.Pages: NewsPage".
```

Shell:

```
<Shell 
x:Class="SmartYard.Shells.ShellSession"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:views="clr-namespace:SmartYard.Pages">
<TabBar>

    <ShellContent
            x:Name="tabNews"
            Title="Новости"
            Icon="file.png"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views: NewsPage}" //ошибка ссылается на эту строку
            Route="NewsPage" />
    .....
```

NewsPage.xaml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SmartYard.Pages.NewsPage"
             Title="Новости">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="news"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

NewsPage.xaml.cs:

```
namespace SmartYard.Pages;

public partial class NewsPage : ContentPage
{
    public NewsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Пересборка:
[image: Процесс пересборки]

Comment: Проект пересоберите.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, не помогло, при пересборке это же исключение выдавало

Comment: Ну проект успешно собрался? Если нет и там только эта ошибка, то удалите из XAML контрол, пересоберите, добавьте. Суть в том, что XAML зачастую узнает о новом коде только тогда, когда будет выполнена **успешная** сборка.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, добавил фрагмент лога пересборки, подскажите, пожалуйста, что такое "контрол" и где он находится?

Comment: Вот это уберите `<ShellContent ..... />` на время сборки, чтоб ошибок не было, а потом верните.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, убрал, пересобрал, после добавил и снова при сборке та же ошибка

Comment: `views: NewsPage` пробел убрать пробовали здесь? И что это за UI? MAUI чтоли?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/maui/xaml/namespaces/ - это тоже полезно почитать.